# CSS only thumbnail slider

Tags: css, slider, thumbnails

I'm trying to make a thumbnail which on hover will move it's image (that's longer than the wrapper) all the way to the left using only CSS and using the `img` element and not a div with `background-image`.

The problem I have is that I don't know how could I find how much to move it given the fact that the images have different widths.

I did [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g5JGd/3) where the left image moves correctly because I calculated how much it needs to be moved and the right image with the same CSS moving incorrectly.

Comment: You might have to resort to making the images all the same width. Or fancy javascript calculations.

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks, The first one is out of the question. In javascript is very simple, I don't need "fancy calculations", but I don't want to use it as it might slow down my webpage.

Comment: One script isn't going to slow down your page to a noticeable degree..

Comment: I don't know the complexity of the script or how bad (or not) the slow down will be, I just assumed it, but if you say so, I think I'll try to do this with `jQuery`

Comment: Yes, I think that's the best way to go. One jQuery script to calculate this will not slow down the page significantly. Especially with today's download speeds.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you're restricting yourself to manipulating the img element alone and not exploring more usual background-image sprite-like hover event manipulations.

Take a look at this [Codrops article](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/06/18/3d-thumbnail-hover-effects/) and their [demo's here](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/3DHoverEffects/) (note there are 5 demo's in the menu).

The techniques offered don't produce the exact end result you're after, but they do include the structure for the type of events and manipulations you'd need to use.

Comment: I'm using `img` elements because they're the most important elements on my websie (photography portofolio) and from what I heard, `img`s are indexed by google and not `div`s with `background-image`

Comment: You're correct that most bots do not index CSS and so background images are not indexed. This is a thumbnail link to the actual image isn't it? Bots will index img tags on your page whether they are visible or not, and more importantly they will follow links to a page that has the full version of your image available as an img tag. Recommend you treat the thumbnail as though it was "just a link" i.e. title it correctly, linking to the page with the actual image you want to present, also titled/named correctly with some clear semantic text describing the image too. You should get good results.

Comment: Yes, it's a smaller version used as thumbnail of the actual photography used. 'Title it correctly' - you're trying to say that i should use the `title` attribute on the link?

Comment: Yes. Although SEO experts generally agree it doesn't help with direct phrase searches, it can help with relevancy. It definitely helps accessibility, screen-readers will read out the descriptions for example. See: http://www.seomoz.org/q/does-the-link-title-attribute-benefit-seo